# How can I create a folder and put one file inside it in Dropbox using java?

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing a Java desktop application and I want to upload a file to Dropbox. That file will be placed inside one folder (the folder name will be my application name).

Currently I am able to upload the file but it is stored into `Apps > Application-Folder -> Live`. So I don't want the `Apps` folder to appear. Instead I only want the application name folder and file that am uploading. Can anybody point me to right direction?

Comment: Worth pointing out that this (Apps > Application Folder) is the designated root area for applications with default permissions, and for security reasons you can't stray outside it. If you want this then I think you'll have to apply for full permissions for your app, which are a lot more difficult to get (if this is the only reason you want full permissions, I doubt they'll be granted en masse.)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the createFolder with move to do what you intend.

```
public DbxEntry move(String fromPath, String toPath) throws DbxException

Move a file or folder from one path in Dropbox to another path in Dropbox.
```

So you create folders a and b on the same level. The you move b into a using the move() method.

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java) you may follow this tutorial..